# Filtering users in TFS Merge Wizard

Tags: tfs

Is it possible in TFS's Merge Wizard to filter the changesets by user or display the changesets only for specific user? If the Merge Wizard does not support this, do you know if some other tool is available?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 'Find Changesets':
[image]

There you can filter per file/user/dates/changeset numbers.