# How to get all unmerged changesets for a branch using TFS 2010 SDK?

Tags: .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

Currently I have 2 branches - Development and Release.

Is it possible to obtain all unmerged changesets from Development to Release?

Currently we use the default Merge Wizzard. However it has one big limitation - it cannot filter by user. So I was thinking of building an app that will pull all unmerged changesets from Development to Release and allow me to filter those changesets by user.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121366/filtering-users-in-tfs-merge-wizard

Answer (score 5):

You could write a small console app that goes like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace UnmergedChangesets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://myserver:8080/collection"));
            VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer) tpc.GetService(typeof (VersionControlServer));
            MergeCandidate[] mergeCandidates = vcs.GetMergeCandidates("$/Development", "$/Release", RecursionType.Full);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get into `mergeCandidates` all changesets that are missing in your `Release` branch.
If you want to further filter for a certain user you can do this with something like that:

```
foreach (var mergeCandidate in mergeCandidates)
{
  if(mergeCandidate.Changeset.Owner == @"DOMAIN\ChuckNorris")
  {
    //This is an unmerged changeset commited by Chuck 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at codeproject if you the standard windows doesn't fit your needs.

Somebody has done such a type of application so you can look how it works

[TFS 2010 SDK: Smart Merge - Programmatically Create your own Merge Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231845/TFS-2010-SDK-Smart-Merge-Programmatically-Create-y)

**Edit**

I forgot, i work with this project template for VS2010

[Visual Studio 2010 Project Template for TFS Utilities](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/11/16/download-visual-studio-2010-project-template-for-tfs-utilities.aspx)