# TFS Unmerged Changes

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I use a simple branching strategy where I have a trunk.  i branch from that trunk into multiple development branches.  Once dev is done I merge the dev branch back into main.

I'm looking for a way to produce an automated report that would tell me which branches have changes that have not yet been merged back into the trunk.

I'm sure there is a way to do this with either tf.exe or the tfs database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all unmerged changesets for a branch using TFS 2010 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201227/how-to-get-all-unmerged-changesets-for-a-branch-using-tfs-2010-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the API... but it would be easiest to just use `tf.exe`. I used to have a Powershell script that I executed once each development cycle to catch unmerged changes.

Use with `vc` or `git` (below example for `vc`):

```
tf.exe vc merge /recursive /candidate "$/source/BRANCH" "$/target/BRANCH"
```

You can get the skinny on all of the tf.exe merge options here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I found Derek's answer to be correct, but there was a small syntax problem in the call to tf.exe.

The correct syntax is:

```
tf.exe merge /recursive /candidate "$/Source/Branch/Location" "$/Target/Branch/Location"
```

This should be run from within a mapped TFS workspace folder, or you may get the error: "Unable to determine the workspace."

You can alternatively use the "workspaces" action on tf.exe before the merge call to specify a collection to target if the machine you're running from has no mapped workspaces.