# How to get change sets not merged between 2 branches using TFS API

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am trying to implement a solution for our internal use and one of the things needed is to query the changesets that are not merged from 1 branch to the other branch.

Its essentially the same as #5 in http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/26/tfs-2010-sdk-smart-merge-programmatically-create-your-own-merge.aspx
But i am trying to find its equivalent in **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi** and **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common**

We have Team Foundation Server 2018 RTW

Comment: If possible, please check if this thread give any help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201227/how-to-get-all-unmerged-changesets-for-a-branch-using-tfs-2010-sdk

Comment: @Alex This seems to be using the same code in the link i mentioned and those ones are obsolete. I cant get it from Nuget either. Thats why i am trying to find its equivalent in the libs  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common